# How do I run a service (Darkice) in the background?

Tags: python, pi-3b+

I am trying to build a one-button Darkice streaming box, I'm using a Pi 3 B+ with Stretch from NOOBS.
I have everything set up but my Python script hangs up as soon as the button is pressed and Darkice runs, using process.call(Darkice). I think this is because it runs Darkice in the foreground, as when one types 'Darkice' in terminal that window becomes 'frozen' until ctrl-c is pressed. 
How do I have the 'Darkice' command run in my Python script so that Darkice runs in the background and the Python script continues beyond starting Darkice?
Apologies if this is super-basic, I'm not a coder.

Comment: Not to take anything away from  @computerjan's answer, but you should read this Q&A also: [How to start a background process in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python)

Comment: As an aside, your question seems to be more of a programming question than a Raspberry Pi question. While the boundaries are a wee bit fuzzy, you should consider which SE site is most appropriate for your question. For example, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is a good place to post programming questions.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't sure where to post it though I've been trawling all of the SE forums for this project

Answer (score 1):

Your script hangs because it does not resume after it run the `darkice` program.

As you described, when running `darkice` in the terminal it is starts and runs indefinitely until the user or another process terminates it - in your case the `ctrl-c` key combination. 
That's why your terminal window appear *frozen*.

A simple approach with standard CLI tools to run a program in the background could be the unix terminal program `screen`, it creates a virtual TTY and comes with raspbian by default.

In your python script you could use the `os` library to call screen using the `os.system()` function instead of `subprocess.call`.
Place the following line of instead of your `subprocress.call("darkice")` in your script:

```
    os.system("screen -S backgroundtty -D -m darkice")
```

and your script should resume after the command while `screen` with `darkice` will run in the background.

You can stop `darkice` using the `kill` command or kill the `screen` that is running `darkice`.

```
    os.system("screen -X -S backgroundtty kill")
```

Comment: Just simply sending darkice to the background with appending `&` to the command does not work?

Comment: @Ingo: that works with a command from the terminal (e.g. `bash`), but the OP's question concerns starting the process from within a Python program.

Comment: Have you also tried doing this with the `subprocess` module? I ask because [I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python) that the `subprocess` module is currently favored over the `os.system` calls. I'm just curious...

Comment: computerjan's solution worked great, I haven't tried the subprocess module, if it aint broke you know?